# How did Lust reform after Roy pulled out her core?

Tags: anime, fma-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist

I've been watching Fullmetal Alchemist and I can't figure out one thing.

In Episode 19, "Death of the Undying," Roy forcibly removes Lust's core / power source:

> In lieu of a heart, she has a philosopher's stone, as do all of the Seven Sin homonculi.

I'm wondering, how does she reform around that? Shouldn't she have died?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Colonel Mustang does rip her Philosopher's stone right from her chest:

[image: Lust vs Mustang]

But while he is holding the stone in his hand, she reforms around the stone from the chunks  of flesh still on the stone.

[image: Lust regrows right around Mustang's hand.]

> A homunculus can be truly destroyed ONLY when their Philosopher's stone has been exhausted AND their body is destroyed. The stone that powers a homunculus is comprised of the lifeforces of the victims that died in its creation. So each time a homunculus take damage equal to a fatal injury, a bit of lifeforce is lost as they regenerate said damage. This is why a battle with a homunculus goes bad for most humans, it is simply too difficult to deal out enough damage against the homunculus before the human is overwhelmed.